# Confusion with .libPaths during package install

Tags: r, install.packages

This will probably be answered by someone directing me to a help file but I'm clearly missing it thus far. My quandry is that when I install a package (sometimes), it does not appear to default to the contents of my .libPaths - instead it appears to want to install to a network path to which it does not have permission.

Here is my library path

```
>.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library"
```

If I try to install this package without specifying the lib argument it seems like it is trying to save to a network folder (I have changed the name of the network drive in the error message but you get the idea):

```
 > install.packages("rmarkdown")
 trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/rmarkdown_0.9.6.zip'
 Content type 'application/zip' length 2182803 bytes (2.1 MB)
 downloaded 2.1 MB

 package ‘rmarkdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

 The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\my.name\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkFVHnn\downloaded_packages
 Warning message:
 In dir.create(configDir, recursive = TRUE) :
 cannot create dir '\\server.name\server_directory', reason 'Permission denied'
```

However, if I specify `.libpaths()` in the "lib" argument, then it works. But isn't this the default to the lib argument?

```
> install.packages("rmarkdown",lib=.libPaths())
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/rmarkdown_0.9.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2182803 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

package ‘rmarkdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\jordan.watson\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkFVHnn\downloaded_packages
```

This does not happen every time however. For example, I just loaded the "forecast" library no problem by simply writing `install.packages("forecast")`.

I'd just like to understand this behavior better. Can someone explain why this is happening? I am on Windows 7 without full admin privileges - but I do have admin privileges to my R folder on the C drive.

Apologies in advance that I can not make a reproducible example - it's not really that type of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jordan,

My feeling is your setup is incorrect.

#### Proposed Solution

Try running the following command and see if this fixes the situation.

**Note:** *I have replaced my `userid` with `<user>` in the examples below.*

```
.libPaths( c( "C:/Users/<user>/Documents/R/win-library/3.3", .libPaths()) )
```

#### Explanation

I would expect `.libPaths()` to return two directories not one by default.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/<user>/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library"
```

When you install R it installs the base libraries under

```
C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library
```

any new libraries are normally added to:

```
"C:/Users/<user>/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"
```

if you type `View(installed.packages())` you will be able to see where the packages are installed.

The packages that come with the R install (base, stats, and nearly 30 others) are stored in the library subdirectory of wherever you installed R. You can retrieve the location of this with:

```
> R.home("library")
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/library"

> .Library
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/library
```

You also get a user library for installing packages that will only be accessible by you. The location under Windows, for R version x.y.z, it is in the R/win-library/x.y subfolder of the home directory, where the home directory can be found via:

```
> path.expand("~")
[1] "C:/Users/<user>/Documents"

> Sys.getenv("HOME")
[1] "C:/Users/<user>/Documents"
```

#### Issue

Thus, I would expect `.libPaths()` to return two paths not one which implies that you have somehow misconfigured the R installation libpath.

I hope the above helps.

Refs:

- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html
- Learning R By: Richard Cotton

Comment: thanks! Indeed you are correct about the "incorrect" (unusual?) configuration of my system. Since I don't have admin rights to all of the C drive but only this one folder, it seems that the win-library folder is on the network drive while the R installation is in C. I'd spent much time with the libPaths help file but hadn't extracted the explanation that you gave. I'm still confused why some libraries work and others don't but I'll keep working on that part....